# How does a fluid interface return both $this and a value?

Tags: php, software-design

I'm relatively new to OOP so browsing through the documentation of Simple HTML DOM I was wondering how its methods use both method chaining and the regular behaviour of returning a value/object.

For example I can do:

```
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html -> find('something'); // Returns object or array of objects
```

but I can also do:

```
 $html -> find('something') -> find('something_else');
```

which, if I understand method chaining properly, implies that `find()` returns `$this` i.e. itself.

Also it's my understanding using method chaining you return `$this`, after which you use a getter method to actually return a value that you can use/want.
For example:

> $object -> add(1) -> add(2) -> getNumber();

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: I can see what you mean, but the thing that trips me up is that `find()` might also return null but I can still use `$object -> find()` again without creating a new object.
Also I can understand that it might return an object, but returning an array of objects? Is the return value an object or array?

Comment: That's why it doesn't make sense to do it that way. Remember that a clear code isn't necessarily a good looking code. Sometimes it's better to have a longer non-optimized but intuitive and easy to read code than something that looks sexy but takes you time to understand and debug it.

Comment: @user2271704: It doesn't look like the code you give with the chained calls would work, as Virus says they normally return an array. Frankly, the API for that library doesn't look good.

Comment: @Jon The API in question is very similar to (I think inspired by) the extremely popular jQuery Javascript library. JS and PHP are obviously very different languages, but the principle of chaining method calls one after another can lead to very elegant code in both.

Comment: @IMSoP: The problem is that this API doesn't go all the way to be a Monad like jQuery does. That's a major selling point for using jQuery, but it doesn't quite apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it does not make sense to call find on the return value of find since that return value is supposed to be an array.

You could eventually add a second parameter to your `find(string, array&)` so you could do :

```
$result1 = [];
$resilt2 = [];

$html -> find('something', $result1)
      -> fint('something else', $result2);

var_dump($result1, $result2);
```

With :

```
public function find($search, & $output) {
    $output = ...
    return $this;
}
```

Depends on your taste.
Chain calls are only usefull if you want to call multiple methods (**that return nothing in particular**) on the same object to avoid rewriting the variable name each time and thus making a shorter code.

EDIT:
If you want to do something like :

```
" $html -> find('div#results') -> find('li a'); "
```

You have a problem because $html respresents a DOM while the value returned by find is not a DOM but a set of results. Your find function could eventually create and return a smaller DOM with #result as a root (this would then be an object of the same class as $html and not an array), and then calling find would perform a search on that new root instead of the document's root, but that looks a bit unintuitive.

Comment: Well the advantage here of chaining would be that I could do:

`$html -> find('div#results') -> find('li a');`

which would supposedly return all `a` in `div#results`.

Is it considered bad design as Jon says?

Comment: By the way, see http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
It does all the work needed to read XML, and HTML is a ase of XML.

Comment: Yeah just change the fr to en =)
There is loadHTMLFile and other methods like that. You don't need to reinvent the wheel unless you do that for practicing.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of chaining you are referring to there involves returning not `$this`, but a new object representing the data found. The trick is to make that object usable *as though* it were an array or scalar, using ["magic methods"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and [pre-defined interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php).

[The SimpleXML extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) makes extensive use of this concept so that every object can simultaneously be used in multiple ways:

- `__toString()`, so that casting to a string, or using in an unambiguous string context like `echo` gives you the text content of an XML node
- [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) so that you can use `$a['href']` to access attributes, and `$li[42]` to access one of multiple matching nodes
- [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) so that you can `foreach` over multiple matches
- `__get()` and `__set()` to search for and over-write child elements by tag name

(Actually, SimpleXML is a binary extension, so cheats a bit, but most of its functionality could theoretically be implemented in plain PHP using the above.)

So for instance this statement:

```
echo $simplexml_element->foo[42]->bar['baz'];
```

appears to contain arrays, hashes, and strings, but is actually a whole chain of object calls, something like this:

```
echo $simplexml_element->__get('foo')->offsetGet(42)->__get('bar')->offsetGet('baz')->__toString();
```

Comment: Ahhh now that explains what I'm seeing. I guess a lot more studying is in order to fully understand what's going on.
You wouldn't perhaps have any pointers or good reading on the subject to get me on my way would you?

Comment: Hm, not sure. I'm a bit of a "learn by example" type myself, so tend to nose into other people's code and experiment rather than wading through tutorials and the like...